# Could not find IEntity

Tags: external-content-type

I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection, which is mainly used to create projects. These projects can contain different phases, which becomes a new subsite when a new project is created. The phases are dependent of information in a external database. SharePoint gives me the following error when I try to create a new project:

> Could not find IEntity with the condition Entity Namespace =
>   http://db/contacts, Name = contacts

I don't have this problem on my local machine, with the exact same source, this problem only occurs when I deploy to a server. Any ideas of where I can search for configuration mistakes?